# OSX: How to add shortcut in right click to open folder with Adobe Brackets?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, brackets

I am a web developer and using [Adobe Brackets](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjl1L3ho6HLAhVEkY4KHe8bC8QQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fbrackets.io%2F&usg=AFQjCNG3RFlu937jGvtrP_cVMjDVN5-qdA) in development. Is it possible to add a shortcut in right click of folder to open the folder with the app. For an example we can add a shortcut to open the folder with terminal.

Many thanks for your attention.